# Adding to user input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to have the use enter an input for a file name, what I would like to do is just have the user type in the name of the file without the extension. Since the only applicable file will be a .txt file it seems redundant to have the user type the extension, so I would like to add the file extension with the code this is what I have so far:

```
 def create_bills(filename, capacity):
    f = open(filename)
    mytable = mkHashTable(capacity)
    for line in f:
        txt = line.strip().split(' $')
        person = Person(txt[0], txt[1])
        if not person.name in keys(mytable):
            mytable = put(mytable, person.name, person.bill)
        elif person.name in keys(mytable):
            index = indexOf(mytable, person.name)
        else:
            pass

def main():
    capacity = int(input("Size of Hashtable: "))
    file = input("Enter file to be read: ")
    filename = (file +'.txt')
    create_bills(filename, capacity)
```

I am unsure of how to actually approach this problem and add the .txt to the user input.
Example:

> > > Please enter a file name:
> > >       help

.... help.txt

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Th3M1k3/Desktop/python/beeb lab/bieberhash.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Th3M1k3/Desktop/python/beeb lab/bieberhash.py", line 28, in main
    create_bills(filename, capacity)
  File "C:/Users/Th3M1k3/Desktop/python/beeb lab/bieberhash.py", line 12, in create_bills
    f = open(filename, '.txt')
ValueError: invalid mode: '.txt'
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your code already does what you're asking for: `file + '.txt'` concatenates whatever string is in `file` (in this case, the user's input) and the literal string `.txt`. (The parentheses don't add anything, but they don't hurt anything but readability.)

Comment: The problem you're most likely getting is that `open(filename, '.txt')` is going to give you some kind of exception about `.txt` not being a valid mode for `open`. The answer is to not pass `'.txt'` as a second argument.

Comment: You should not be getting that error from the code you have posted -- did you update your actual code with the same `open` call?

Comment: Yes I've done exactly what you see, which is why I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you are already adding `.txt` to the file name entered by the user.  You do not need to add it again in the open call in `create_bills()`.

Comment: its not working either way i attempt it is there a specific way to add to a user input

Comment: @Cos: You're going to have to put whatever traceback you are getting in your question so we can see what the problem is.  As far as adding `.txt` to the file name and opening a file goes, your code looks fine.  Hmmm... you might want to put a `.strip()` on the input line in case the user is putting extra spaces either before or after the name.